# Thread safe counter using OpenMP

Tags: openmp, c++14

What are solutions to the hazards in doing this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main(){

    int k = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){

        if (i % 2){ /** Conditional based on i **/
            #pragma omp atomic
            k++;

            usleep(1000 * ((float)std::rand() / RAND_MAX));

            #pragma omp task
            std::cout << k << std::endl; /** Some sort of task **/
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I need all `k`s to be unique. What would be a better way of doing this?

## Edit

Notice how [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569954/how-to-manage-shared-variable-in-openmp) refers to an **aggregate**

In particular I want to spawn tasks based on a shared variable. I run the risk of having a race condition.

Consider thread 2 completes, evaluates true for the conditional, and increments k before thread 1 spawns all tasks.

## Edit edit

I tried to force a race condition. It wasn't obvious without the sleep. There are in fact problems. How can I overcome this.

Here's a quick solution:

```
...    
#pragma omp atomic
k++;
int c = k;
...
```

but I'd like a guarantee.

Tangential. Why doesn't this implementation work?

```
...
int c;
#pragma omp crtical
{
    k++;
    c = k;
}
...
```

At the end of the function, `std::cout << k;`, is consistently less than the expected 50000 output [proof](https://gist.github.com/dmadisetti/28c92a4478d7aa0553be49ec54859aca)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manage shared variable in OpenMp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569954/how-to-manage-shared-variable-in-openmp)

Comment: @Igor Updated answer highlighting difference

Comment: The `critical` variant should in deed work as in 1) `k == 50000` at the end of the loop `c == (i+1)/2`. You should however `std::cout << c` during the loop and read `k` only within the critical section our outside of the parllel loop.

Comment: @Zulan I know right! but here's the output https://gist.github.com/dmadisetti/28c92a4478d7aa0553be49ec54859aca it doesn't work

Comment: You have a typo in `critical`. Compile your code with `-Wall` (and even `-Werror`) to avoid such issues.

Comment: Also note that `std::rand` is safe and/or efficient to use in multi-threaded code, although I assume you just use it for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @Zulan thank you, I was a bit hasty in making the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to answer my question so quickly, but I found a solution for this particular instance.

As of OpenMP 3.1 there is the ["atomic capture"](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/608588#GUID-FD64C97E-2537-4535-AC97-74B46CCCD355) pragma

The use case is for problems just like this. The resultant code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main(){

    int k = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){

        if (i % 2){ /** Conditional based on i **/
            int c;
            #pragma omp atomic capture
            {
                c = k;
                k++;
            }

            usleep(1000 * ((float)std::rand() / RAND_MAX));

            #pragma omp task
            std::cout << c << std::endl; /** Some sort of task **/
        }
    }
    std::cout << k << std::endl; /** Some sort of task **/
    std::cout.flush();
    return 0;
}
```

I will leave this problem open if someone would like to contribute ideas/ code arch. suggestions for avoiding these problems, reasons the `#pragma omp crtical` didn't work

Comment: `atomic capture` is the right thing to do in your case.

Comment: none of them worked for me. I am using visual studio